# Extracting the time series of all pixel values in the study area for one band in an image collection in Google Earth Engine in a CSV file

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have an image collection in Google Earth Engine in different dates, I want to extract the time series of all pixels in the study area for one band in the image collection in a CSV file. In fact I want to analyze the changes in each pixel value in that variable through the time. Each row in the table may include latitude and longitude of pixel and the columns should be the value of the variable at each date. Last questions applied some points to extract the pixel values but I want to know is it possible to extract all pixel values without defining points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably run into problems doing this for larger areas and/or longer time series, but you could do something like this:

```
var scale = 10
var bands = ['B2', 'B3']
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED')
  .filterDate('2022-07-01', '2022-07-15')
  .filterBounds(geometry)
  .map(extractPixels)
  .flatten()

print(collection)
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: collection, 
  selectors: ['date', 'latitude', 'longitude'].concat(bands)
})

function extractPixels(image) {
  var mask = ee.Image(1) // Create some mask - remove clouds etc.
  var pixels = image
    .select(bands)
    .addBands(ee.Image.pixelLonLat())
    .updateMask(image.mask().reduce(ee.Reducer.min())) // Mask everything if something is masked
    .updateMask(mask)
    .reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.toList(), 
      geometry: geometry, 
      scale: scale,
      maxPixels: 1e13
    })
  
  return ee.FeatureCollection(
    ee.Array(pixels.values())
      .transpose()
      .toList()
      .map(function (values) {
        var properties = ee.Dictionary.fromLists(pixels.keys(), values)
        return ee.Feature(null, properties)
          .set('date', image.date().format('yyyy-MM-dd'))
      })
  )
}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/965f23f04efaae3dd16bc8365a5ba7b6