# Allowing null outputs when mapping over FeatureCollection in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, csv, null

I have code working that extracts the area of forest loss from the Hansen Global Forest Change dataset for each available year and attaches it to the properties of a mapped FeatureCollection. This worked fine for the test FeatureCollection with 3 polygons and there was valid data to attach. When it maps over a feature that does not have any data associated with it, I get the error

```
"Array: No numbers in 'values', must provide a type."
```

you can see that the properties are the same:
[image: Array: No numbers in 'values', must provide a type.]

It looks like [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/439915/dealing-with-missing-values-in-the-following-code) is what I need to do, but I'm not sure how to change it from image-based data to the grouped reducer

```
//var working_aoi = ee.FeatureCollection("users/jrobertsonpanthera/surveyed_grid_3test")
//var aoi = ee.FeatureCollection("users/jrobertsonpanthera/surveyed_grid_4test")

// Hansen Data
var gfc = ee.Image('UMD/hansen/global_forest_change_2022_v1_10')
var lossImage = gfc.select(['loss'])
var lossAreaImage = lossImage.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea())

var lossYear = gfc.select(['lossyear'])

var stats = aoi.map(function (feature) {
  var tuples = ee.List(lossAreaImage
    .addBands(lossYear)
    .reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().group({groupField: 1}),
      geometry: feature.geometry(),
      scale: 30,
      maxPixels: 1e13
    })
    .get('groups')
  ).map(function (group) {
    group = ee.Dictionary(group)
    var year = group.getNumber('group').add(2000)
    var area = group.getNumber('sum')
    return [year, area]
  })
  var yearsAreas = ee.Array(tuples).transpose()
  var years = yearsAreas
    .slice(0, 0, 1)
    .project([1])
    .toList()
    .map(function (year) {
      return ee.Number(year).format('loss_%d')
    })
  var areas = yearsAreas
    .slice(0, 1)
    .project([1])
    .toList()
  return ee.Feature(feature.geometry(), ee.Dictionary.fromLists(years, areas))
    .set('id', feature.get('id'))
})

print(stats)

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: stats, 
  description: 'loss'
})

//show aoi, zoom the map
Map.addLayer(ee.Image().paint(aoi, 1, 3), null, 'region'); 
Map.centerObject(aoi,9);

//show the loss layer
var treeLossVisParam = {
  bands: ['lossyear'],
  min: 0,
  max: 1,
  palette: ['yellow', 'red']
};
Map.addLayer(gfc, treeLossVisParam, 'tree loss year');
```

Code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/b61d4528df6a3259ace7712f87569230

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the below should do the trick. It first extracts the groups, adds them to the feature as a property, adds a property to indicate if there aren't any groups, filters out features without groups, then, using the groups from the feature, continue with the logic from before.

```
var stats = aoi
  .map(function (feature) {
    var groups = ee.List(lossAreaImage
      .addBands(lossYear)
      .reduceRegion({
        reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().group({groupField: 1}),
        geometry: feature.geometry(),
        scale: 30,
        maxPixels: 1e13
      })
      .get('groups')
    )
    return feature
      .set('groups', groups)
      .set('empty', groups.size().eq(0))
  })
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('empty', 0))
  .map(function (feature) {
    var tuples = ee.List(feature.get('groups'))
      .map(function (group) {
        ...
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/6df42e1c8d03298a4bece53785153994